# Scroll left/right to selected image in photo reel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

Please visit http://lindseymotors.com/v and click the photo up top of the silver truck. When the expanded view pops up, there is a row of photos below the main photo. When you click on them, it switches to that photo and says "Viewing" over the image you selected.

I need this to also scroll left or right (depending on which one is clicked) to focus on the one that says "viewing" in the middle of the photo reel.

The image being viewed is accessible by using `$('#vehiclePhotoPreview'+photoID)`

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
var currentPhotoPosition = $('#vehiclePhotoPreview'+photoID).position();
$('.vehicleDetailExpandedPhotoReel').scrollLeft(currentPhotoPosition.left);
```

Comment: This is a big request, why not use a image slider plugin like www.jssor.com.

Comment: What do you mean it's a big request? I'm just looking for a way to find the position of a specific element and scroll to the position of that element.

Answer (score 0):

`$().posotion` gives you absolute position unfortunately. It won't be helpful in this case.

```
var increment = $('#vehiclePhotoPreview' + photoID).width() + 10; //10 would be the space between each image

$('.vehicleDetailExpandedPhotoReel').scrollLeft(photoID * increment); //assuming that photoID is always sequential
```

That essentially will get the position by using the active number and the current increment to set the scroll position.

Comment: I tried something like that but it only works in one direction. If I click photo #3 it scrolls do it, but if I select photo #1 after I select photo #3 it will not scroll back to photo #1. Any solutions to make it work both ways?